# Create a facebook Login button like Apple Signin

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

So to do a button that has "Sign in with Apple" I have used the following code.

```
let appleButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()
        appleButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(appleButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            appleButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            appleButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30),
            appleButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30)
        ])
```

Which works great.

Is there a code like this for Facebook as I want all the buttons to look the same if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned here [Facebook Swift SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login/) you can do something like this:

```
import FacebookLogin

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let loginButton = FBLoginButton(readPermissions: [ .publicProfile ])
       loginButton.center = view.center

       view.addSubview(loginButton)
   }

}
```

Comment: and what is the function it calls if user logins?

Comment: Did you try to tap the button? I always made a custom button and after that i followed the documentation and "Custom Login Button" paragraph

Comment: I ideally don't want to make a custom button I would like to use the default one. I have noticed one a user has signed in it does update to Logout. Which is cool so their must be away to function it response too.

Comment: Reading Facebook documentation i found this: To get notifications of login results or logout events assign a delegate to FBLoginButton that conforms to the LoginButtonDelegate protocol. So, if you extends this protocol you will be able to use Facebbok button and manage login response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func SignWithFacebookTochUp(_ sender: Any) {
    loginWithFaceBook()
}

func loginWithFaceBook() {
    LoginManager().logIn(permissions: [.publicProfile,.userPhotos, .userGender, .userBirthday, .email, .userFriends, .custom("user_posts")], viewController: self, completion: didReceiveFacebookLoginResult)
}

func didReceiveFacebookLoginResult(loginResult: LoginResult) {
    switch loginResult {
    case .success:
        didLoginWithFacebook()
    case let .failed(error):
        baseAlert!.close()
        self.showErrorAlert(title: loginError, message: error.localizedDescription)
        break
    case .cancelled:
        baseAlert!.close()
        break
    }
}

func didLoginWithFacebook() {
    if let accessToken = AccessToken.current {
        // If Firebase enabled, we log the user into Firebase
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessToken.tokenString)) { (authDataResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
               // error
            } else {
                // success
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to have a custom button. I am trying to use just the default FBLoginButton - wondering how to get response.